# relative clause

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> With most children there are certain years of childhood, which every
>   parent feels ought to free from the burden and responsibilities of the
>   life.

In this sentence, why is a comma needed after '**childhood**' making a nonrestrictive relative clause?

Comment: That is a good question. This sentence sounds very awkward to me, and I am not sure the "which" introduces a nonrestrictive relative clause. I am also not sure it is correct to separate "from" and "which" in this way. In addition, "free" is a transitive verb and I don't see a direct object here. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: The original sentence doesn't have a comma and the question is to corrent it grammatically. I wonder why it needs a comma to be grammatical.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there's a comma or not. It's ungrammatical at worst—and somewhat nonsensical at best. I don't know what's it's trying to convey in the first place. (Neither *feels ought to free* or *responsibilities of the life* make sense.)